# Extracting values for a specific key-value pair in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a Dataframe for whom one of the columns has a list of nested dicts. I am trying to fetch value pertaining to a specific key.

Given below is how the Dataframe looks like:

```
sale_id, sale_detail
10001, [{
         'compulsory_on_complete': True,
         'name': 'Store Location',  <-- Pull value corresponding to this as given in the next row
         'value': 'London',   
         'value_id': 2}, 
        {
         'compulsory_on_complete': True,
         'name': 'Product Category', <-- Pull value corresponding to this as given in the next row
         'value': 'General',
         'value_id': 5}] 
10002, [{
         'compulsory_on_complete': True,
         'name': 'Store Location',
         'value': 'Scotland',
         'value_id': 2}, 
        {
         'compulsory_on_complete': True,
         'name': 'Product Category',
         'value': 'Supplies',
         'value_id': 5}]
```

Expected output:

```
sale_id, store_location, product_category
10001, London, General
10002, Scotland, Supplies
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run an `apply` on the `sale_detail` column to extract the data:

```
import ast

def get_detail(sale_detail):
    result = {}
    for detail in ast.literal_eval(sale_detail):
        if detail.get('name') == 'Store Location':
            result['store_location'] = detail.get('value')
        elif detail.get('name') == 'Product Category':
            result['product_category'] = detail.get('value')

    return result

detail = df['sale_detail'].apply(get_detail).to_list()
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(detail)], axis=1)
```

**Edit**: since the `sale_detail` column is of type string, we need to first convert it to an array of dicts with `ast.literal_eval(...)`.

Comment: thanks for the help. I am however getting an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` when I run `detail = df['sale_detail'].apply(get_detail).to_list()`

Comment: What does `type(df.loc[0, 'sale_detail'])` print?

Comment: it returns `str`

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry I assumed it was an array of dictionaries

Comment: thanks this gave another error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_list'`.. Sorry but any advice on that..

Comment: Check your pandas version: `pd.__version__` I think `to_list()` was added in 0.24. I am running 1.0

Comment: thank you, it was with my pandas version that caused the last error..